# C# how to include button click events in foor loop

Tags: c#, xamarin

im trying to build an quiz app with xamarin.

I have an issue, when i press a button (when i answer the question) for loop doesn't return.

Basiccially, i have a quizz app, and when i answer the question, mysql reader must run again and should give me the second record of table, on another answer sould show me third record of table.

here is my code.

```
            for (int soruid = 1; soruid < sorusayisi; soruid++)
            {

            

                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand sorualıcıx = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + Testler.testno + " WHERE soruid= " + sorusayaci + " ", con);
                MySqlDataReader oku = sorualıcıx.ExecuteReader();
                while (oku.Read())
                {

                    Random rastgele = new Random();
                    int rndm = rastgele.Next(5);
                    if (rndm < 2)
                    {
                        a.Text = oku.GetString("cevap");
                        soru.Text = oku.GetString("soru");
                        b.Text = oku.GetString("yanliscevap1");
                        c.Text = oku.GetString("yanliscevap2");
                        d.Text = oku.GetString("yanliscevap3");
                        correctanswer = true;
                        cevapa = true;
                        cevapb = false;
                        cevapc = false;
                        cevapd = false;

                    }
                    else if (rndm == 2)
                    {
                        b.Text = oku.GetString("cevap");
                        soru.Text = oku.GetString("soru");
                        a.Text = oku.GetString("yanliscevap1");
                        c.Text = oku.GetString("yanliscevap2");
                        d.Text = oku.GetString("yanliscevap3");

                        cevapb = true;
                        cevapa = false;
                        cevapc = false;
                        cevapd = false;

                    }
            ......


                        a.Clicked += A_Clicked;
                        b.Clicked += B_Clicked;
                        c.Clicked += C_Clicked;
                        d.Clicked += D_Clicked;

                    void D_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        if (cevapd == true)
                        {
                            sorusayaci++;
                            d.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
                            a.IsEnabled = false;
                            b.IsEnabled = false;
                            c.IsEnabled = false;

                        }

                        else if (cevapa == true)
                        {
                            sorusayaci++;
                            a.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
                            d.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                            b.IsEnabled = false;
                            c.IsEnabled = false;

                        }
                        else if (cevapb == true)
                        {
                            sorusayaci++;
                            b.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
                            d.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                            a.IsEnabled = false;
                            c.IsEnabled = false;


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sorusayaci++;
                            c.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
                            d.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                            a.IsEnabled = false;
                            b.IsEnabled = false;

                        }


                    }

                    void C_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        if (cevapc == true)
                        {
                            sorusayaci++;
                            c.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
                            a.IsEnabled = false;
                            b.IsEnabled = false;
                            d.IsEnabled = false;

                        }
                        else if (cevapa == true)
                        {
                            sorusayaci++;
                            a.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
                            c.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                            b.IsEnabled = false;
                            d.IsEnabled = false;

                        }
                        else if (cevapb == true)
                        {
                            sorusayaci++;
                            b.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
                            c.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                            a.IsEnabled = false;
                            d.IsEnabled = false;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sorusayaci++;
                            d.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
                            c.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                            a.IsEnabled = false;
                            b.IsEnabled = false;

                        }
                    }
```

for loop's bracket ends end of the code.

Comment: No intent to offend you, but this code looks like a mess and that's where your confusion comes from. I don't even know, where to start. Separate concerns, make methods and functions that do _one_ thing, don't use turquish "i" in code, consider naming your vars english because most of us won't speak your language but understand english by definition (since SO is in english, only) ... list goes on. As is, unanswerable.

Comment: thanks for your opinion, im new in this job, i know i have a lot of way in this job

Comment: That's ok. I am only afraid that you won't get a satisfying answer, because there's just too much to address. Don't let that push you away from this platform, it's awesome and helped me a lot - in answering my questions and learning from others. I don't even know what to suggest (other than "improve your code" which is not very helpful). And I feel bad for it, honestly.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the goal here is to create a state machine. I.e. each button the user clicks result in a new state, with other buttons to click.

One patter is to let [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) build the state machine. This may be simpler to read since it allows you to write a method in a fairly straight forward way, i.e. something like this:

```
for each question
    show question
    await users answer
    if( answer is correct )
         continue
    else
        show error
        break
```

For this to work you would need a task that completes when the user has pressed a button, or done some other action. This can be done with something like this:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public event EventHandler MyEvent;
        public void Raise() => MyEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public static Task OnEventTask(this MyClass handler)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        handler.MyEvent += OnElapsed;
        
        void OnElapsed(object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            tcs.SetResult(true);
            handler.MyEvent -= OnElapsed;
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Just replace MyClass with a button or whatever class you want to listen on events to. Do note that the event handler will only be removed when the event fires, so if it never fires it might cause an event handler leak. You can also use Task.WhenAny or WhenAll to handle multiple events.